# Newbie to sed - parsing a text file for data

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Suppose I have a string like this

```
Some random words here 25 ms
```

I want to extract 25 and put it into another text file. How do I go about this?

Basically each line has some words in the beginning and a floating point decimal followed by **ms** at the end. 25 was just given as an example.

Comment: Do you want to extract any sort of number or just integers?

Comment: Edit your question to describe in words how you would want to find "25" in that string so we're not guessing. Is it because it's a number or because it's the last field on the line or because it's the 5th field or because it follows the word "here" or....

Comment: Corrected. There was an error in my question.

Comment: @Mithrandir Any type of numbers. Guess I was vague. Updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `awk` by printing the penultimate field only:

```
$ awk '{print $(NF-1)}' <<< "Some random words here 25 ms" 
25
```

In `grep` with [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
grep -Po "[0-9.]+(?= ms)"  <<< "Some random words here 25 ms" 
25
```

Comment: There was a mistake in my original question. Really sorry for the trouble. Could you please update the answer?

Comment: Sure, just print `NF-1` i.e the 2nd from last field.

Answer (score 0):

where the 25 should go? have you finished your question?

based on current version of your question. so the 25 is not random.
just

```
echo "25" > another.file
```

if 25 is random number, always at the end of that line:

```
grep -oE '[0-9]+$' <<<" Some random words here 25" > another.file
```

**EDIT**

```
grep -Po '\d+(?= ms)' <<<"Some random words here 25 ms" > another.file
```

Comment: There was a mistake in my original question. Really sorry for the trouble. Could you please update the answer?

Comment: This doesn't work for floating points :( Does \d mean integers? What do we use for floating point decimals?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/[^0-9. ]*//g' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: There was a mistake in my original question. Really sorry for the trouble. Could you please update the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I would scan for the last word that consists of only numbers (that may optionally have decimal places) just before `ms`.

```
sed 's/.* \([0-9.]*\) ms$/\1/' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: There was a mistake in my original question. Really sorry for the trouble. Could you please update the answer?

Comment: If I input "This is 23.231 ms" it outputs 231 but it should output 23.231. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

If there are lines who dont have ms in the end then you can do this as well

`awk '$NF ~ /ms/{print $(NF-1)}' temp.txt`

It will pick only those lines whose last field has `ms`